# ASP.NET Identity , how to expire token programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I have a scenario like ,

When something change on `User` like `CompanyId` or User's `BirthDay` changed ,
I want to expire or invalid User Token and than generate new token.

How can I do that with ASP.NET Identity Framework.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the issued access_token? How do you create these tokens?

Comment: Identity creates that for me from this endpoint '../api/token' basic and it goes to OAuthProvider , and there is method for ApplicationUser GenerateUserIdentityAsync these are doing the work.

Comment: change the `SecurityStamp` - this will invalidate tokens and cookies

Comment: I am using this in WEB API so I dont use OAuthCookieProvider I am using ApplicationOAuthProvider , so that when I update my SecurityStamp this token still valid because it is not going to db to check is SecurityStamp updated.